# Gitlab CI for Android having problems with running functional tests

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup GitLab CI for android but my builds keep failing with this error: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. Failed to start emulator : error: no emulators found.

For reference, [here's](https://ghostbin.com/paste/scebu) what my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like. The file from their documentation/tutorial article is outdated and doesn't work now, and every other implementation out there fails for one reason or the other. If someone  has worked with this before, I'd really appreciate some help here.

Comment: the android emulator moved from android-sdk/tools android-sdk/emulator, for me this solved this issue